# Упоминания как ВКонтакте вида @id1(паша)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$text = ' @id27(Мы сделаем это) '
$text = preg_replace('#@id[0-9]+\(+[a-zа-я]+\)#is', '<u>$0</u>', $text);
```

Хотел сделать "упоминания" как вконтакте, но не понял до конца как сделать всё это. Данный код обработал бы [@id](/users/3123/idanil)27(NAME) и вывел бы этот текст подчёркнутым, но с русскими буквами это не срабатывает.
К тому же я не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы [@id](/users/3123/idanil)27( и ) убирались, и делалась ссылка вида

```
<a href="/id27">Мы сделаем это</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модификатор [**u**](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Все просто, очень просто.

```
$a = '@id27(Мы сделаем это)';
var_dump(preg_replace('/@id\d+\(([a-zа-я\s]+)\)/iu', '<u>$0</u>', $a));
var_dump(preg_replace('/@id(\d+)\(([a-zа-я\s]+)\)/iu', '<a href="/id$1">$2</a>', $a));
```

Comment: А как же на счёт ()!*#

Comment: Не понял Вас.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы там нельзя было вставить символы ()!*#
а то получается, если я пишу @id1(паша дурак @id2(норм)) - выведет @id1(паша дурак <a href="/id2">норм</a>)

Comment: Я дал мысль как делать, дальше сами.

Answer (score 0):

Как насчёт другого регекса?

```
'#@id[0-9]+\([^\)]+\)#is'
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы там нельзя было вставить символы ()!*#

Comment: Дело не в содержимом регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно, чтобы там нельзя было вставить символы ()!*# а то получается, если я пишу @id1(паша дурак @id2(норм)) - выведет @id1(паша дурак <a href="/id2">норм</a>)

Так и [добавьте эти символы в регулярку](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/%40id(%5Cd%2B)%5C((%5Ba-z%D0%B0-%D1%8F0-9%5C(%5C)%5C%40%5C!%5C*%5C%23%5Cs%5D%2B)%5C)%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%40id1(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%40id2(%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC))/)

Answer (score 0):

Там используется калбек на проверку юзернейма. Учитывайте это.